# How to open an Excel file directly from a Powershell script?

Tags: excel, powershell, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, powershell-7.2

I'm using Powershell version 7.2.1

When I run the command below on Powershell, it works fine, i.e. Excel is launched and the target Excel file is opened.

```
& 'PATH_TO_EXCEL_EXE' 'PATH_TO_TARGET_FILE'
```

Howewer, when I pass this command to a scheduled task, Excel is launched but the target file isn't opened. More details about my Powershell script:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "& 'PATH_TO_EXCEL_EXE' 'PATH_TO_TARGET_FILE'"
...
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "myTask"
# The line below is for testing purpose, to see if my scheduled task can launch correctly.
Start-ScheduledTask -TaskName "myTask"
```

Can someone tell me the reason why Powershell fails to replicate the action, when it's passed to a scheduled task as above? Any workarounds/solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's because you need to provide the user it needs to run under as. Can you try that?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala How to do that?

Comment: Using the `-User` parameter with `Register-ScheduledTask`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala That didn't work. To clarify, Excel program is opened when the scheduled task is run, but the file isn't opened. I performed all the operations with the same user and passed -User param to Register-ScheduledTask as you suggested.

Comment: Can you run the following [function](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/4925-run-task-schedule-under-users-context)? It works for me when I do it, and it uses the same concept.

Comment: What about this: $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'PATH_TO_EXCEL_EXE' -Argument 'PATH_TO_TARGET_FILE'

Comment: @ZivkoK Thanks for the comment. I think this solves my issue. I've added as an answer. Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on ZivkoK's comment, I'm adding an answer which solves the issue:

```
$excelExePath = ...
$excelFile = ...
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $excelExePath -Argument """$excelFile"""
```

A scheduled task based on the action above does what it intends to do.

P.S. Triple quotes surrounding excelFile parameter are needed when the excel file path contains space characters. For example, if the excel file path is "C:\MyUser\some random file.xlsx", then Excel tries to open 3 files named "some", "random", and "file.xlsx". Using triple quotes solves this problem.

Comment: Glad that it works. I would also suggest to surround $excelExePath with double-quotes... and you can use the escape character (`") instead of triple quotes (""") if you prefer.